# Representing the images of unit vectors in a 3 by 3 matrix

Tags: matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

I've been looking at different sources to see how the transformed unit vectors are displayed in a 3 by 3 matrix, but there seems to be some contradiction.

In my textbook, they give a shear example.

$x' = x$
$y' = y + z$
$z' = z$

$M=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$

This is where my confusion lies. If $y' = y + z$, then $y'=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ but they have have written the second column as $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's *not* true that
$$y'=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
(Obviously, since $y'$ is a scalar and $(0,1,1)^t$ is a vector!)

What's true is that
$$y'=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix},$$
which corresponds to the second row in the matrix.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome! You can mark the question as "answered" by clicking on the check mark (so that others can see on the front page that it's already been answered).